# How to get a LocalDateTime from a callback and convert it to UTC time format?

Tags: java, utc, mapstruct, localdatetime

How can I get an existing `LocalDateTime` (I get it from a callback) and be able to convert it to `UTC` format?

```
public static LocalDateTime convertXMLGregorianCalendarToDateUTC(XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar) {
    // Next shows GMT or UTC
    return LocalDateTime.of(xmlGregorianCalendar.getYear(), xmlGregorianCalendar.getMonth(),
            xmlGregorianCalendar.getDay(), xmlGregorianCalendar.getHour(), xmlGregorianCalendar.getMinute(),
            xmlGregorianCalendar.getSecond());
}
```

I'm using mapstruct for mappings :

```
@Mapping(target = "targetDateTime", source = "sourceDateTime", qualifiedByName = "timeToUTC")
})
void updateFolderEntity(FolderEntity folderEntity);
```

I have a simple helper to make a function that take what callback gives me and return it in UTC :

```
@Named("timeToUTC")
public LocalDateTime timeToUTC(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
    // stuck here !
 return DateUtils.convertXMLGregorianCalendarToDateUTC(callBackUserService.getUser().get(0).getDateAction());
}
```

The problem is that `callBackUserService.getUser().get(0).getDateAction()` is actually the date I need to convert but mapStruct doesn't allow me to make the mapping as `CallBackUserService callBackUserService` cannot be a parameter in `public LocalDateTime timeToUTC(LocalDateTime localDateTime)`  because my source is `sourceDateTime` and it's only one type and it's `LocalDateTime`

Comment: The LocalDateTime object does not represent a Date and Time in UTC. It represents a date and time without knowledge of timezones or offsets.  OffsetDateTime is the proper java.time object to represent a date based on UTC offsets.

Comment: Your `updateFolderEntity` method has single parameter. Why?